# quot to &quot; in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

the sample is

```
<script>
 $('#data').jstree({
            'core': {
                'data': [@:{"text" : "ABC"},           @subtree();]}})

@function {
    public string subtree(){
        return  "{\"text\" : \"ABC\"}, "
    }
}
</script>
```

it will become

```
 $('#data').jstree({
                'core': {
                    'data': [{"text" : "ABC"},{&quot;text&quot; : &quot;ABC&quot;},]}})
```

I need to output `quot`. And I need function to recursive. How can I solve it?

Comment: Please reword your question. It is not clear what you want or what the problem is.

Comment: What do you mean by, the function needs to be recursive?

Comment: The answer is at the below .Thx everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the string output of the `@subtree();` call is automatically escaped, you should prevent that by calling `Html.Raw`:

```
'data': [@:{"text" : "ABC"},           @Html.Raw(subtree());]}})
```